# Can we use the word "pierce" for making big holes in something?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

To me, the word "pierce" means making holes in something but it also connotes that the hole being made is very narrow and tight, which is why it doesn't sound right to use it to talk about woodpeckers pecking on trees and making almost big holes. But what is a word we can use to talk about that kind of hole making in something? (I assume the word "puncture" is similar to "pierce")

Edit: I'm not looking for a word specific to making holes on trees by woodpeckers. I'm looking for a verb for making big holes in something, if there is such a verb.

Comment: It *pecked* a hole in the wood.

Comment: I edited the title of your question. It was very misleading—because it immediately invited the verb *peck*. Later in the question, you added an edit to say you weren't looking for what a woodpecker does specifically, but you'd left the original title.

Comment: *I'm looking for a verb for making big holes in something,* Please give an example sentence: There are several verbs but they depend on what is making the hole and what material the hole is made in.

Comment: The verb 'pierce' carries no implications of the size of any aperture created.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey so "a woodpecker __pierces__ the trunk of a tree to find food" is okay?

Comment: @Askeladd   Yes, it's OK. A needle pierces a piece of paper to make a hole 0.1mm wide; a tunnel boring machine pierces a mountain to make a hole 10 metres wide.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If talking about big holes, I would use [**bore**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bore):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> *transitive verb*
> **1** : to pierce with a turning or twisting movement of a tool
>     // *bore* a wooden post
> **2** : to make by boring or digging away material
>     // *bored* a tunnel
>     // use a drill to *bore* a hole through the board
> *intransitive verb*
> **1 a** : to make a hole by or as if by boring
>     // insects that *bore* into trees
> **1 b** : to sink a mine shaft or well
>     // *boring* for oil

The example sentence of "insects that *bore* into trees" is particularly apt if making a comparison to woodpeckers.

Comment: Thank you very much. And by the way, I don't know who downvoted your answer. I upvoted it.

Comment: @Askeladd Thank you. It seems that several people decided to downvote *all* of the answers, so this was something not liked in general. I don't know why either.

Answer (score -1):

*Drill* may be what you’re looking for.

drill, verb:

make hole with a tool

INTRANSITIVE/TRANSITIVE ♪

to make a hole using a special tool or machine

drill something in something: Drill two holes in the wall.

drill through: They had to drill through the mountainside.

drill for oil/gas: They are drilling for oil in the area.

(Macmillan) https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/drill_2#drill_19

A woodpecker is actually looking for insects, but creates a narrow channel in the wood. Narrow channels can be created by awls in leather, picks, bullets (in human flesh).

Answer (score -1):

A number of different verbs are used for the behaviour of woodpeckers: *drill*, *bore holes* etc. If you wish to sound formal and scientific, you may use *excavate*.
Interesting fact: these birds 'peck'  only for their feeding purposes; they also *drum* and *tap* without *puncturing* to communicate with their own species and other creatures for purposes such as reproduction or intimation of territoriality.